# How do I configure Prettier such that a single attribute tag does not reformat to multiline?

Tags: html, eslint, prettier

I tried setting the Print Width to a high number which temporarily solved the issue but I do not want this number to be too large as it is actually useful for long html tags with many attributes to be broken down into multi line. However, for an html tag with only one class name for example, I want Prettier to keep it like this:

```
<div class="header_info">
```

Rather than what Prettier is automatically reformatting it to as follows:

```
<div 
  class="header_info
>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set `printWidth` or put `// prettier-ignore` comment above your code.

Answer (score 0):

This was introduced before some time:

`<!-- prettier-ignore-attribute *ngFor -->` will exclude the *ngFor (angular attribute) from being formatted.

This works for all kinds of attributes in HTML files.